# Access to static properties via this.constructor in typescript

Tags: typescript, this, static-methods, static-members, typescript1.6

I want to write es6 class:

```
class SomeClass {
    static prop = 123

    method() {
    }
}
```

How to get access to static `prop` from `method()` without use `SomeClass` explicitly? In es6 it can be done with `this.constructor`, but in typescript `this.constructor.prop` causes error "*TS2339: Property 'prop' does not exist on type 'Function'*".

Comment: Have you tried 'this.constructor["prop"]'?

Comment: This is not a solution: I have completely miss type chek in that case. I want to get error on access non existing property.

Comment: Can you share your actual code? In what context are you trying to do it?

Comment: @ArturEshenbrener you could do `(this.constructor as typeof SomeClass).prop`, but what's the point? Why not do `SomeClass.prop`?

Answer (score 38):

> but in typescript this.constructor.prop causes error "TS2339: Property 'prop' does not exist on type 'Function'".

Typescript does not infer the type of `constructor` to be anything beyond `Function` (after all ... the constructor might be a sub class).

So use an assertion:

```
class SomeClass {
    static prop = 123;
    method() {
        (this.constructor as typeof SomeClass).prop;
    }
}
```

[More on assertions](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html)

Comment: I use `self` as static context like PHP `const self = this.constructor as typeof SomeClass;`

Answer (score 27):

Microsoft programmer talking this but there is not a good way to type `constructor`. You can use this tip first.

```
class SomeClass {
    /**
     * @see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841#issuecomment-337560146
     */
    ['constructor']: typeof SomeClass

    static prop = 123

    method() {
        this.constructor.prop // number
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting though that you should not invoke the constructor if you do this, since a subclass doesn't necessarily have the same signature.

Answer (score 5):

I guess that you want in the future extends this class. So it is better to do this:

```ts
class SomeClass<T extends typeof SomeClass = typeof SomeClass> {
    static prop = 123

    method() {
        (this.constructor as T).prop;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Accessing static properties through `this.constructor` (as opposed to just doing `SomeClass.prop` like normally you would) is only ever useful when you don't know the name of the class and have to use `this` instead. `typeof this` doesn't work, so here's my workaround:

```
class SomeClass {

  static prop = 123;

  method() {

    const that = this;

    type Type = {
      constructor: Type;
      prop: number; //only need to define the static props you're going to need
    } & typeof that;

    (this as Type).constructor.prop;
  }

}
```

Or, when using it outside the class:

```
class SomeClass {
  static prop = 123;
  method() {
    console.log(
      getPropFromAnyClass(this)
    );
  }
}

function getPropFromAnyClass<T>(target: T) {
  type Type = {
    constructor: Type;
    prop: number; //only need to define the static props you're going to need
  } & T;

  return (target as Type).constructor.prop;
}
```

Comment: Presumably you lean on `this.constructor` so as to not break inheritance, no?

Answer (score -1):

Usually the simple way is:

```
class SomeClass {
    static prop = 123

    method() {
        console.log(SomeClass.prop)  //> 123
    }
}
```

Note that if you use this, subclasses of `SomeClass` will access the `SomeClass.prop` directly rather than `SomeSubClass.prop`. Use basarat's method if you want subclasses to access their own static properties of the same name.

Comment: The question states "without use SomeClass explicitly". I'm confused on how this provides an answer.