# TypeScript: Property 'propertyName' does not exist on type 'Function'

Tags: javascript, typescript

TypeScript compiler is giving me an error on the following code example although the generated JavaScript on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ works as intended

The error is: ***error TS2339: Property 'tableName' does not exist on type 'Function'.***

```
class ActiveRecord {
    static tableName(): string { // override this
        return "active_record";
    }

    static findOne(): any {
        return 'Finding a record on table: ' + this.tableName();
    }

    save(): void {
        console.log('Saving record to table: ' + this.constructor.tableName());
    }
}

class MyModel extends ActiveRecord {
    static tableName(): string {
        return "my_model";
    }
}

let x = new MyModel();
x.save(); // "Saving record on table: my_model"
console.log(MyModel.findOne()); // "Finding a record on table: my_model"
```

Is there is anything I can do to fix this error?

Comment: Using ActiveRecord.tableName() will not call the overriding method of the subclass which will break the intended behavior @Joe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix the TypeScript error and still get the intended behavior (not using ActiveRecord.tableName()) you can cast the constructor to a typeof ActiveRecord

```
(this.constructor as typeof ActiveRecord).tableName())
```

Reference link: [Access to static properties via this.constructor in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387318/access-to-static-properties-via-this-constructor-in-typescript)

Answer (score 3):

Replace this

```
this.constructor.tableName()
```

With this

```
ActiveRecord.tableName()
```

As a static function is must be called using the class namespace.

Comment: This would break OP's functionality - `this.constructor` can call static methods from current(child) instance. Your solution is for when you'd be *calling static method from a static method in the **same class*** :-)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to NOT use the static keyword on your properties. Otherwise use ActiveRecord.tableName()

Comment: `ActiveRecord.tableName()` would always return the parent class table name, not the child class. But yes, the whole thing could by bypassed by simply not using static methods.