# How to refer to a static property of the child class from a non-static method in the parent class?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to refer to a static property defined in my child class, from a non-static method in my parent class, but can't figure a way to achieve this. Is this possible in any case?

```
class Parent {
    static staticList: {
        a: number
    } = {
        a: 1
    };

    public test<TParent extends Parent>(this: TParent, key: keyof TParent['constructor']['staticList']) { /** can't figure out how to refer to the constructor class of the this parameter here */
        console.log(this.constructor.staticList[key]); /** while this logs out the correct information, why is typescript complaining about this line? */
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    static staticList: {
        a: number
        b: number
    } = {
        a: 2,
        b: 2
    }
}

const childInstance = new Child();
childInstance.test('a'); /** this correctly logs out 2, and it should type hint me to "a" or "b", instead of the "never" */
```

Here's a fiddle for my problem also: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=25&ssc=124&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALtA3gKGn6EaYaAlsAUacADImEBcWu+LYjKArgLYBGSCzPAF9oAXiYtWjAIyDoQgNzY5ABw48QZaGiSEAPABV4ydNCQAPHSgAmMY6jQA+ABRoAFnUZHEDgDTQAayQAT0Yg4IB7ADNobxM0AG0AcmAIlEIEDmA0CIQkgF1kwmIyWkICgEosaAB6ACo66GAwFCSMKJIAcw5kaAiODDcIgHdtCOhkKP4x7TckJrSMrJyEJvAoPpj3efc6aBVEMC4kHVW53rqauRZU9IiQJAA6EAjO1w8IR9ul7NzH4qoZUS4XyFQUtQa0GGHgesz2L06MH6GG2CwQyGy0BIKCiuS4JTS-mhwSxMDQwRUumACBIKgwqS4KnA2OxnWgYB4yLhME0KCQAH5oJc5EJsKLsKBIDAAMIw6xmSyoWxwHymHAsAFaTU0OhoRjqyR4NjQTi8fjXfA8djcPgCFgicQGw3GgBMvgteCt0BdIrFym+9yeCOcACIABIAUQAShGQ2CJYt6XKAJLpIgoYDzcR80aykggazOePAFNplqZx46QjOJJgJJgiGNXYwVLopDZEAkhFIgbe-wteUkDAQIYcAvaCnzDymY4zENgEN9VYhngh-zYwhIMDy6KzeYhvkAN34i8uQA)

Answer (score 1):

This has been an [issue in TypeScript for some time](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841). Your code example is completely alright. If you want to bypass this issue, you can do this as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33404548/17277491):

```
(this.constructor as typeof Parent).staticList
```

Another part is the type of argument, which you would like to be as the key of the `staticList` property of the current class the argument is in. This can't be done with TypeScript and I would recommend you not to do this, because it's [against the Liskov substitution principle](https://stackify.com/solid-design-liskov-substitution-principle/). The type of the argument of the child class can be only more *general* and not more *concrete* than the super class argument. Imagine you have code, which works with the `Parent` class. You can pass an instance of the `Parent` class to this code and it would work just alright. And if you pass any sub-class of `Parent` (like `Child`), this code would work as well. But imagine you have `staticList` on `Parent` with key `[1]` and sub-class of `Parent` which have `staticList` with keys like `[2, 3]`. Now, if you pass this sub-class to this code, which knows how to work with `Parent`, it will cause an error, because the code expects the argument to accept only key with value `1` (because the `Parent` accepts it), but the sub-class accepts `2` and `3`.

If you want to validate your argument based on your `staticList` keys, just insert a code inside your method, that checks, if the key is present in the current `staticList`.

Comment: this still doesn't solve the type hinting problem, and the additional errors

Comment: @AdamBaranyai I have edited my answer a tried to explain the _argument type_ problem.

Comment: maybe I will get frowned upon for this, but I never really agreed with the Liskov substitution principle. maybe because I am a self learned programmer, and no one explained it to me really well, but I find it to go against common sense: why would, for example a *Dog* be more generic then an *Animal*, instead of it being a more concrete *Animal*?

Comment: @AdamBaranyai I really suggest you to read [the article I have mentioned in the answer](https://stackify.com/solid-design-liskov-substitution-principle/).

Comment: @AdamBaranyai BTW the `Dog` is not more generic. It is more concrete.