# TypeScript access static property on child class

Tags: typescript

I am using TypeScript to represent a complex model in OOP form. There is one parent class `Base` which sets some values used in almost *every* class so I don't have repetitive code.

I am using the [debug](https://npmjs.com/package/debug) npm package for debug logging, hoping to have logs looking similar to the following:

```
  mypkg:DataModel:0  This is the first time I ran new DataModel().
  mypkg:OtherMdls:0  And this is the first time I ran new OtherMdls().
  mypkg:DataModel:1  This is a log from the second instance of DataModel.
```

I am obtaining this result by having the abstract Base class store a `static _instanceID` property and a `private _instanceID` property similar to this:

```
abstract class Base {
  static _instanceID = 0;
  private _instanceID;
  protected _log: debug.Debugger;
  
  constructor() {
    this._instanceID = Base._instanceID++;
    this._log = debug(`mypkg:${this.constructor.name}:${this._instanceID}`);
  }
}
```

The value `this.constructor.name` seems to resolve to whatever the class created's name is, which results in the type of log I want, no matter how many times the class is extended.

The problem is, let's create some extra empty classes:

```
class A extends Base {}
class B extends Base {}
class C extends Base {}
```

Now, I am going to create a few of each of these classes and log their `_instanceID` values.

```
new A(); // _instanceID = 0 ; expected
new A(); // _instanceID = 1 ; expected
new B(); // _instanceID = 2 ; what? expected 0
```

I understand the logic here. The `Base` class is using it's own `_instanceID` because of this line:

```
    this._instanceID = Base._instanceID++;
//                     ^^^^
```

Now what I want to do is actually increment the static `_instanceID` on the *inheriting* class, so that I get results similar to:

```
new A(); // 0
new A(); // 1
new B(); // 0
new C(); // 0
new B(); // 1
new A(); // 1
new C(); // 1
new C(); // 2
```

You get the gist by now. How can I fix this?

Also, **without passing properties in the `super()` call,** is it possible to make the logs show all inherited classes, similar to `mypkg:DataModel:SubModel:Thing:0` or is this too bulky and could it just be `mypkg:DataModel:0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to reference the [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) for the static id, similar to how you use it to retrieve the name.

The downside is there are currently [no good ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387318/access-to-static-properties-via-this-constructor-in-typescript) to infer the type of the `constructor`. The linked question shows a few options that serve as a workaround though.

```js
class Base {
  static _instanceID = 0;
  _instanceID;

  constructor() {
    this._instanceID = this.constructor._instanceID++;
    console.log(this.constructor.name, this._instanceID);
  }
}

class A extends Base {}
class B extends Base {}
class C extends Base {}

new A(); // 0
new A(); // 1
new A(); // 2
new B(); // 0
new B(); // 1
new C(); // 0
new C(); // 1
new C(); // 2
```

Comment: Ahah! That explains where my problem was. I had found this solution, but I was confused why `B.constructor._instanceID` was undefined... but I realized, just now, I needed to execute `(new B()).constructor._instanceID` instead!